# Number format issue, newbie project

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I am trying to write a program that loads a movie data base file, and then splits up that information into the movie title, year, and all of the associated actors. I split up all of the info, but I am having issues converting the year, which is in a string, to an int. The format of the year string is (****) with the * being a year, such as 1999. When I try to use parse I get a number format exception. I have tried replacing the parentheses, but it just gave me more errors! Any ideas?

```
public class MovieDatabase {

ArrayList<Movie> allMovie = new ArrayList<Movie>();

//Loading the text file and breaking it apart into sections
public void loadDataFromFile( String aFileName) throws FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner theScanner = new Scanner(aFileName);
    theScanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("cast-mpaa.txt"));

    while(theScanner.hasNextLine()){
        String line = theScanner.nextLine();
        String[] splitting = line.split("/" );
        String movieTitleAndYear = splitting[0];
        int movieYearIndex = movieTitleAndYear.indexOf("(");
        String movieYear = movieTitleAndYear.substring(movieYearIndex);
        System.out.println(movieYear);
        //this is where I have issues
        int theYear = Integer.parseInt(movieYear);
        String movieTitle = movieTitleAndYear.substring(0, movieYearIndex);
        ArrayList<Actor> allActors = new ArrayList<Actor>();
        for ( int i = 1; i < splitting.length; i++){
            String[] names = splitting[i].split(",");
            String firstName = names[0];
            Actor theActor = new Actor(firstName);
            ArrayList<Actor> allActor = new ArrayList<Actor>();
            allActor.add(theActor);
        }

        Movie theMovie = new Movie(movieTitle, theYear, allActors);
        allMovie.add(theMovie);

    }       
    theScanner.close();
}
```

output:

```
(1967)
```

Here is the errors I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "(1967)"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
at MovieDatabase.loadDataFromFile(MovieDatabase.java:27)
```

Comment: Add the stacktrace please. And sample data from the file.

Comment: Print `movieYear` before parsing it to `int`

Comment: And print the value of `movieYear`.

Comment: Agreed with JBNizet, printing movieYear will show you your issue. Most probably issue is with end of substring. In substring(movieYearIndex); you are only mentioning start of year string but not end of year string index

Comment: if the year is like (xxxx), line  String movieYear = movieTitleAndYear.substring(movieYearIndex); is wrong cause it will return String like xxxx)

Answer (score 1):

You have brackets around the numbers. You could either correct your file or you could remove brackets using:

```
String str = "(1967)";
System.out.println(str.substring(1, str.length()-1));
Output:
1967
```

In your code, you used:

```
int movieYearIndex = movieTitleAndYear.indexOf("(");
String movieYear = movieTitleAndYear.substring(movieYearIndex);
```

So if my movieTitleAndYear string is "hi (1947)", indexOf will give me index of "(" as 3 and substring will start reading string from index 3 which includes "(". One way you could avoid opening bracket is to change your substring line to:

```
String movieYear = movieTitleAndYear.substring(movieYearIndex + 1);//but still you have closing bracket.
```

If you are sure it's always going to be of four digit, then you could do something like:

```
String movieYear = movieTitleAndYear.substring(movieYearIndex + 1, movieYearIndex  + 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `substring` call currently gets a year enclosed by brackets, e.g., `(1967)`. You can avoid this by calling the [substring variant that accepts an endIndex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-), and just get the year's four digits:

```
String movieYear = 
    movieTitleAndYear.substring(movieYearIndex + 1, // to get rid of "("
                                movieYearIndex + 5 // to get rid of ")" 
                               );
```

Comment: You are missing a coma between two parameters :)

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie how embarrassing :-) Thanks! (fixed)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add indexof for ")". 
Code snippet:

```
int movieYearOpenBracesIndex = movieTitleAndYear.indexOf("(");
int movieYearCloseBracesIndex = movieTitleAndYear.indexOf(")");
String movieYear = movieTitleAndYear.substring(movieYearOpenBracesIndex + 1, movieYearCloseBracesIndex);
System.out.println(movieYear);
```

This will give the exact year. e.g. 1967